# Selecionando o VALOR de um select com javascript ou jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte problema:

Preciso selecionar o valor de um `select` no `html` para executar um laço `if` em `javascript` ou `jquery`, como fazer ?

```
<select class="input">
    <option default disabled="disabled">--</option>
    <option value="">TESTE1</option>
    <option value="">TESTE2</option>
    <option value="">TESTE3</option>
</select>
```

no caso, o valor do `select`, quando for diferente da primeira opção, essa primeira opção dada como `default` será excluída do `html`

Comment: obrigado, vou fazer uma resposta própria ao problema, assim pode acabar facilitando pro pessoal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar algumas `id`'s, e um valor ao campo que deseja apagar, caso o select não tenha o valor `0` por exemplo, então ele remove o mesmo, que tem por `id` '`default-selecionado`'

HTML

```
<select class="input" id="selecionar-categoria">
    <option default disabled="disabled" id="default-selected" value="0">--</option>
    <option value="">TESTE1</option>
    <option value="">TESTE2</option>
    <option value="">TESTE3</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
$("#selecionar-categoria").on('change', function(){
   if($(this).val() != '0'){
     $("#default-select").remove();
   };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode resolver assim:

```js
var selectTeste = document.getElementById('selectTeste');
if (selectTeste.selectedIndex !== 0) {
  selectTeste.removeChild(selectTeste.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<select class="input" id="selectTeste">
    <option default disabled="disabled">--</option>
    <option value="TESTE1">TESTE1</option>
    <option value="TESTE2">TESTE2</option>
    <option value="TESTE3">TESTE3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Exemplo em Javascript puro:

```html
<select id="select">
  <option disabled selected>Escolha...</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>  
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>  
</select>

<script>
  document.querySelector('#select').onchange = function() {
    if(this.querySelector(':disabled')) {
      this.querySelector(':disabled').remove();
    }
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
  }
</script>
```

Exemplo com jQuery (muda só o script):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option disabled selected>Escolha...</option>
  <option value="aaa">AAA</option>
  <option value="bbb">BBB</option>  
  <option value="ccc">CCC</option>  
</select>

<script>
  $('#select').change(function() {
    $(this).find(":disabled").remove();
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    console.log(selectedValue);
  });
</script>
```